# C++ how to sort dynamically using lambda functions for a vector of unique_ptrs?

Tags: sorting, lambda, c++11, unique-ptr

So I have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> vec` and I'm trying to sort it dynamically, given that there are logical comparisons between Derived1 to Derivedn (Derivedn always > Derivedn-1 > ... > Derived1) (say n = 10 or so) and each Derivedx has it's own different comparison with Derivedx.  As an example, think 10 digit integer > 9 digit integer > 1 digit integer, but within each derived class 53 > 32 (but I'm not sorting integers).

So I can do this:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
[](std::unique_ptr<Base>& const a, std::unique_ptr<Base>& const b){
  return *a<*b;}
```

And then in Base, have a function `Base::operator<(const Base& b)` make comparisons if they are different Derived classes, and cast to Derivedx if they are the same with `Derivedx::operator<(const Derivedx& d)` if they are the same derived.

However, I would think that there's a way that I can compare a to b automatically given the appropriate definitions in the derived classes, but I have been unable to implement it due to compile errors.  I cannot get the lambda function to compare Derivedx < Derivedy dynamically.

I've tried `Base::operator<(const std::unique_ptr<Base>)` and then use `return *a<b` for a compiler error, saying that I used a deleted copy assignment operator (which I don't understand, where is the assignment??).  An abstract virtual `Base::operator<(const Base& b)` does practically the same thing I'm doing now with more work because I have to implement `Derivedx::operator<(const Base& b)` (for each Derivedx) and then cast down to (Derivedx) if they're the same.

It may just be better that I compare everything in the base class rather than implementing n^2 comparisons in (n comparisons in n derived classes) though.  But I do want to see if I can keep things "object oriented".

Any thoughts on the design issue?
Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice the multimethods proposal had made it into the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Chapter 31, *Making functions virtual with respect to more than one object* in Scott Meyers, *More Effective C++*.

Also, try googling on the phrases *double dispatch* and *multiple dispatch*.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I probably would have used overriding the `operator<` with the set of relevant variants. This would then be independent from any class hierarchy. But maybe this is not what you want.